# How to get the customer attribute value?

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, customer, customer-attribute

### What I want

- add customer attribute
- show the new attribute in front(dashboard) page

### Problem

I have created customer attribute with this code below:

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$vCustomerEntityType = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$vCustAttributeSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($vCustomerEntityType);
$vCustAttributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'manager', array(
        'label' => 'Account Manager',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        'forms' => array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'),
            'visible' => true,
            'global' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => 1,
        'required' => false,
        'default_value' => 'default',
        'user_defined' => true,
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId, $vCustAttributeGroupId, 'manager', 0);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'manager');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'));
$oAttribute->save();


echo "DONE";
exit;
```

And then, this part was normally works. I can find new form in backend and I can update the form with new data. That was good so far but I couldn't get the data in front page section.

When I have searched this problem, the below code seems to normally working but it wasn't work for me.

I put below code in  `/app/design/frontend/<Theme>/default/template/customer/account/dashboard.phtml`.

```
$attr = $this->getCustomer()->getAttribute('manager')->getData($customer);
// not working

$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$attr = $customer->getAttribute('manager')->getData($customer);
// not working

$_customerModel = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$_customer = $customerModel->load($this->getCustomer()->getId());
$attr = $_customer->getAttribute('manager')->getData($_customer);
// Yeah, still not working

$attr = $this->getCustomer()->getAttribute('manager')->getData('manager');
// not working but getData('firstname') is working
```

I think the custom attribute was not fully loaded when the customer loaded. Also it seems to be problem with new version of magento. I couldn't find same problem anywhere.

Can I get the data by force such as connecting to database directly or am I missing something in this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get the value of the customer attribute in this way:

```
$customerObj  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$attr = $customerObj->getData('manager');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's a same code what I tried. By the way, is it right the code for creating attribute?

Comment: Sorry. I solved it. You're right. I mean, it was correct. I've got a wrong user information.

Comment: no problem, I am glad it helped. Cheers!

Comment: how to set data?

Answer (score 2):

You should try [This link](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/)

to create customer attriube.

Just open above link and create module for your customer attribute as `Need Add Customer Attribute` wity yes it will ask detail for your attribute and it's ready to use with your magento.

Eg. if you are creating your attribute like `manager` then just add fill the form and create your module.then after you will get your attribute value with cusotomer model like`$customer->getManager()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Refer the below mentioned coding for Get Logged In Customer’s details**

```
//Check if any customer is logged in or not


if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

    // Load the customer's data
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $customer->getPrefix();
    $customer->getName(); // Full Name
    $customer->getFirstname(); // First Name
    $customer->getMiddlename(); // Middle Name
    $customer->getLastname(); // Last Name
    $customer->getSuffix();

    // All other customer data
    $customer->getWebsiteId(); // ID
    $customer->getEntityId(); // ID
    $customer->getEntityTypeId(); // ID
    $customer->getAttributeSetId(); // ID
    $customer->getEmail();
    $customer->getGroupId(); // ID
    $customer->getStoreId(); // ID
    $customer->getCreatedAt(); // yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+01:00
    $customer->getUpdatedAt(); // yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
    $customer->getIsActive(); // 1
    $customer->getDisableAutoGroupChange();
    $customer->getTaxvat();
    $customer->getPasswordHash();
    $customer->getCreatedIn(); // Admin
    $customer->getGender(); // ID
    $customer->getDefaultBilling(); // ID
    $customer->getDefaultShipping(); // ID
    $customer->getDob(); // yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
    $customer->getTaxClassId(); // ID
}
```