# Adding Customer Attribute Value in customer information

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, customer

I have a customer attribute named "tescoclubcard_number", the attribute is not displayed in customer model whereas is displayed in collection.

Can anyone please let me know how i can save the customer attribute value. To load the customer data i have done below:

```
$custData = $order->getData();
$custEmail = $custData['customer_email'];
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$data = $customer->loadByEmail($custEmail);
```

in data i am not getting the attribute "tescoclubcard_number" whereas it is there in collection.

Please let me know how i can save it.

**EDIT**

Another problem i am facing is, when i store tescoclubcard_number value in session and complete the payment using sagepay server the session values are destroyed. Is there a way to keep sessions in tact and use them on success page?

Comment: Please checkout which version of Sage pay you are using, because customer session bug was fixed in **Version 3.0.24.3** released on **04-Mar-2015**. See the change log here: http://ebizmarts.com/magento/suite-changelog.txt and here: http://ext.topmage.com/Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite.html

Comment: See the source code here for bug fix: https://github.com/ebizmarts/sage-pay-suite-ce/commit/93a6db9f5779dd9a7ff7b06e2f6fcb2a43cb1248 but I would suggest you to update whole module rather than changing code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the customer attribute value by following:

```
$customerObj  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$attr = $customerObj->getData('tescoclubcard_number');
```

check out: [How to get the customer attribute value?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17941/how-to-get-the-customer-attribute-value)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.. but the thing is that i need to set the tescoclubcard_number value and setData('tescoclubcard_number') = "123" is not working

Comment: @Dexter after that, try $customerObj->save(); see reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845039/programmatically-setting-a-custom-customer-attribute