# coupon code at level checkout in Magento 1

Tags: checkout, magento-1, discount, promotions, coupon-codes

kindly note i need to display a coupon code worth 10% for selection of products to all clients once they checkout any product from my store; i.e. I made a transaction for a washer worth 500$, i need to show this user a promo code near the product description, you will benefit a 10% discount on all dryers lets say with a promo code or coupon code.

Comment: Do you want to show coupon code on product detail page or once customer add the product then on checkout page you want to show?

Comment: no not on the checkout or even add to cart, yes on the detail page i need to show like a message or drop down, once you purchase this washer you will benefit 10% discount on all washers available on the store. thanks shubham for the great support and fast reply.

Comment: so we can do one thing why dont we show a simple message on  product detail page that if you buy this product then you will get 10% discount using this coupon code. for showing this message create a cms block and then call that block on your product detail page by checking the categories id like if you selected x category only then this block message will show.hope this approach help.

Comment: we can show this as message of course and as block like you are saying but, effectively, how this end user will benefit from a promo next time on the dryers? i mean we need a validation for the promo code, i need to set a rule for the promo code if this user made a purchase on the washer then this promo code will be valid, how can we do that? online shopping cart already checked and dead end!

Comment: Yes exactly we need to create a rule for that and as far as in my knowledge we can set number of time single user can use that code what i understand by your above comment is that user can only use this promo code only on washers is it? If its like this then it can be done by the rule which you will create where we can restrict this promo code for specific category or product.

Comment: hello dear appreciate your perfect support and follow up. the concept is : the user once he made a successful transaction on washer, then he will benefit a 10% discount promo code on dryers. for the message i will display it beside the name with a text field, but, what about the rule and the validation of the promo code? how can i make sure that this user made a transaction before so we can display for him this text and make this code valid?

Comment: hey thanks for your kind words and i am happy to support because i am also learning new things form it so to the point i am not sure it is a right way or not but we can do one thing let's say if user made a transaction on washer so we can create a attribute for a customer and update it let's say '1'  and the next time if user come then we can check customer attribute like if the value of attibute is 1 then only we will show the message and  he can apply that code may be this approach will work but it need customisation in your code.

Comment: AHAAAAAAAAAA yesssssssssssss this is it! i believe you found the solution, how can i make this with coding? shall i customize the view.phtml or anything in the products detail page or what? as for the online shopping rules, i shall create one for washers with 10% discount only and of course for registered clients, right?

Comment: yes it need customisation in your code let me give you full explanation in answer.

Comment: ok perfect! waiting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey You have to do Following things to achieve this:

1. Create a customer attribute let's say **promo_code** for creating this you can use [this](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/customers/customer-attributes-create.html) link.
2. once you created a customer code and customer bought a washer for your site at that time you need to update this attribute value which is a simple task like if customer make transaction then from using customer session you can load customer and can update the **promo_code** attribute value.
3. Once we updated the value of **promo_code** attribute and customer come back again to your site then on Product detail page you can show the promo code which you create for 10% off so that customer can apply it there is also a good thing which is we can set that how many times customer can use the same promo code.for showing the message i would recommend you to create a cms block and on product detail page check if **promo_code** value is updated then only show this message else no.
4. Create Promo code for 10% discount.
5. For getting customer data you have to load the customer by id you can go through [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17941/how-to-get-the-customer-attribute-value) link.
6. Now if you want user only use **promo_code** once then you can again update the value of **promo_code** once customer used it so that next time that message won't appear on your product detail page.

**Get promo_code value using below code:**

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
     $customer_promo_code = $customerData->getPromoCode();
 }
?>
```

Now $customer_promo_code using this variable you can find out the value of promo code which you created.

once you have this you can now use this variable for showing message like:

```
if($customer_promo_code == 1){//check what value you get if yes (1 or 0)
//call the cms block
}
```

Hope this approach help.

Comment: i hope i give a proper information if you have any other query you can ask here.

Comment: hello dear thanks for the great answer; just need to ask you the attribute what type should it be? yes/no or what? and as for the promo code 10% discount everything is clean and clear except point 5 ; what do you mean by loading the customer ID? shall i write a code like the link saying in the customer.phtml? there is many answers in the link can you be more specific since i am testing this right now as we speak.

Comment: dear kindly note i created a promo code 10% for dryers and i created a promo_code attribute for customer but i'm still missing the message in the product details page, i couldn't make it by CMS BLOCK please help! also i need the validation of the promo_code how to display or valid the promo code?

Comment: ok so we will go one by one 
1. we can take it as yes/no because we just need to identity one value.
2 . loading customer id means if you want to update the value of promo_code for that you need to load the customer then only you can set the value of promo_code.

Comment: for showing message on product detail page you have to call a cms block on it and you have to put the pormo code(which you generate by rule) statically in message.and about validation when you were creating promo code you can see one option says like "Uses per Customer" by this you can validate that one customer can use this promo code only once not next time. i hope i cleared all your query's. :)

Comment: I set the promo code to yes/no for the customer attribute. as for the value of promo_code to be enable or hidden as per the customer ID, here is the trick! how can we make that? is it by coding or creating a CMS block or by online shopping cart price rules? can you support me or we need a third party?

Comment: yes i can support you.when user buy any product at that time we will change value of promo_code attribute to yes we are cleared about it ok now if customer come back then at product detail page we have to check is promo_code value is YES if yes then we will call the block for message else we will not call it.

Comment: how can i show or display the message at level only category washer and write of course my promo code? i mean this message is enabled only on category washer and will be hidden on all other categories. this is what i want! so how shall i make validation of the block to be shown only on this category ID and only this one?

Comment: so i think we need to create an if for the block in the product detail page: app/design/frontend/tv_arion_package/tv_arion/template/catalog/product/view.phtml  equal the category ID then we can display the block otherwise should be hidden, correct me please if i am wrong?

Comment: yes correct in view.phtml you have to create if else condition.

Comment: Can you help me making this condition please in order to avoid mistakes and to confirm while testing the final layout and design?

Comment: hey i have updated the answer please check.

Comment: there is an error in the code since we didnt set the if equal to the desired category: <?php
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
     $customer_promo_code = $customerData->getPromoCode();
 }
if($customer_promo_code == 1){//check what value you get if yes (1 or 0)
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('promo')->toHtml(); ?>
}

?>

Comment: i hope you are working on product detail page in view.phtml file and customer is also logged in.

Comment: your line of code in the answer shouldn't be right below each other or separated?

Comment: if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
     $customer_promo_code = $customerData->getPromoCode();
 }
?>


this code will only use for getting promo_code attibute value

the next code will execute at some other place of file.

Comment: lets chat here
 https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84902/coupon-code

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq. :( i am new to this!!

Comment: anyway i will check this now: if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
     $customer_promo_code = $customerData->getPromoCode();
 }
?> then in the same file same location view.phtml i shall add :if($customer_promo_code == 1){//check what value you get if yes (1 or 0)
//call the cms block
}

Comment: yes once you have the coupon code value then only you can show and hide the message.I hope now we can chat in room... :)

Comment: @Marcos i hope you find this answer helpful.